# Difference between Docker cp, docker export and docker save

Tags: docker

I need to do some process with the file from a docker container even the SO files, I know that in order to achieve this I can use docker export, from an image, for example for mysql, I can create a container with the command:

`docker create -ti --name mysql_dummy mysql bash`, and then export the container: `docker export <containerName > <path>/mysql.tar`

I can do the same with the save command:

```
docker save mysql > path/mysql.tar
```

And with the docker cp, using the same container created above:

```
docker cp mysql_dummy:/. <path>
```

My question is what is the difference between these 3 way, I noticed that the save command, save the image created a folder structure with different hashes, such as:

[image]

I'm curious if we can consolidate all of this layers in just one copy of the image.

Which command is the most recommendable and what are the differences, thanks!

Comment: I'd normally recommend avoiding all three commands.  (There are specific unusual cases where you must use `save`; `cp` would be an emergency debugging tool; I'm not sure when you'd use `export`.)  Can you use something like an HTTP GET request to your application to get the file out instead of trying to break Docker's filesystem isolation?

Comment: I don't have any control over the containers so I can't use something like HTTP GET